# How do I resolve this issue with 3D image visualization?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, multidimensional-array, plot, visualization

I have this 3D image data that I need to visualize. I have been able to visualize it with 2D slices using `imshow3D`, but I would like to see the image data in 3D space.

The code I used is as follows (courtesy: [How do i create a rectangular mask at known angles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42662789/how-do-i-create-a-rectangular-mask-at-known-angles/42664658?noredirect=1#comment72490501_42664658)), but I can't tell why it isn't displaying:

```
% create input image
imageSizeX = 120;
imageSizeY = 200;
imageSizeZ = 50

% generate 3D grid
[columnsInImage, rowsInImage, pagesInImage] = meshgrid(1:imageSizeX, 1:imageSizeY, 1:imageSizeZ);

% create the sphere in the image.
centerY  = imageSizeY/2;
centerX  = imageSizeX/2;
centerZ  = imageSizeZ/2;
diameter = 56;
radius   = diameter/2;

sphereVoxels = (rowsInImage - centerY).^2 ...
    + (columnsInImage - centerX).^2 + (pagesInImage - centerZ).^2 <= radius.^2;


% change image from logical to numeric labels.
Img   = double(sphereVoxels);
for ii = 1:numel(Img)
    if Img(ii) == 0
        Img(ii) = 2;  % intermediate phase voxels
    end 
 end



% specify the desired angle
angle = 60;                     

% specify desired pixel height and width of solid
width  = imageSizeX;    
height = imageSizeY;
page   = imageSizeZ;

% Find the row point at which theta will be created
y = centerY - ( radius*cos(angle * pi/180) ) 

% determine top of the solid bar
y0 = max(1, y-height); 

% label everything from y0 to y to be = 3 (solid)
Img(y0:y, 1:width, 1:page)=3;   
% figure, imshow3D(Img);
% axis on;
% grid on;


% display it using an isosurface 
fv = isosurface(Img, 0);
patch(fv,'FaceColor',[0 0 .7],'EdgeColor',[0 0 1]);  title('Binary volume of a sphere');
view(45,45);
axis tight;
grid on;
xlabel('x-axis [pixels]'); ylabel('y-axis [pixels]'); zlabel('z-axis [pixels]')
```

Although, the solid bar is not diagonal as the figure attached below, I would expect the image to be something similar to this:

[image]

I do not know exactly what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Also, if you'd actually like to render the volume like in your sample image (i.e. a "voxelated" Minecraft-like view) instead of with isosurfaces, I could give you a solution for that.

Comment: Oh i see! thanks @gnovice, please i would be glad to have this solution. Many, many thanks for your kindness...

Comment: Related: [Visualize a three-dimensional array like cubic lattice using MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29229988/52738)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With regard to the problem in your code, it appears that you set points inside the sphere to 1, then set all the remaining points outside the sphere to 2, then a section through the y plane to 3. There is no value of 0 in the volume in this case, so trying to get an [`isosurface`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isosurface.html) at the value of 0 isn't going to find anything.

However, if you'd rather create a "voxelated" Minecraft-like surface, like in your sample image showing the facets of your voxels, then I have another option for you...

First, I created a set of volume data as you did in your example, with the exception that I omitted the for loop that sets values to 2, and instead set the values of the solid bar to 2.

Next, I made use of a function `build_voxels` that I've used in a few 3D projects of mine:

```
function [X, Y, Z, C] = build_voxels(roiMask)
  maskSize = size(roiMask);

  % Create the ROI surface patches pointing toward -x:
  index = find(diff(padarray(roiMask, [1 0 0], 'pre'), 1, 1) > 0);
  [X1, Y1, Z1, C1] = make_patches([-1 -1 -1 -1], [1 1 -1 -1], [-1 1 1 -1]);

  % Create the ROI surface patches pointing toward +x:
  index = find(diff(padarray(roiMask, [1 0 0], 'post'), 1, 1) < 0);
  [X2, Y2, Z2, C2] = make_patches([1 1 1 1], [-1 -1 1 1], [-1 1 1 -1]);

  % Create the ROI surface patches pointing toward -y:
  index = find(diff(padarray(roiMask, [0 1 0], 'pre'), 1, 2) > 0);
  [X3, Y3, Z3, C3] = make_patches([-1 -1 1 1], [-1 -1 -1 -1], [-1 1 1 -1]);

  % Create the ROI surface patches pointing toward +y:
  index = find(diff(padarray(roiMask, [0 1 0], 'post'), 1, 2) < 0);
  [X4, Y4, Z4, C4] = make_patches([1 1 -1 -1], [1 1 1 1], [-1 1 1 -1]);

  % Create the ROI surface patches pointing toward -z:
  index = find(diff(padarray(roiMask, [0 0 1], 'pre'), 1, 3) > 0);
  [X5, Y5, Z5, C5] = make_patches([1 1 -1 -1], [-1 1 1 -1], [-1 -1 -1 -1]);

  % Create the ROI surface patches pointing toward +z:
  index = find(diff(padarray(roiMask, [0 0 1], 'post'), 1, 3) < 0);
  [X6, Y6, Z6, C6] = make_patches([-1 -1 1 1], [-1 1 1 -1], [1 1 1 1]);

  % Collect patch data:
  X = [X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6];
  Y = [Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4 Y5 Y6];
  Z = [Z1 Z2 Z3 Z4 Z5 Z6];
  C = [C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6];

  function [Xp, Yp, Zp, Cp] = make_patches(Xo, Yo, Zo)
    [Xp, Yp, Zp] = ind2sub(maskSize, index);
    Xp = bsxfun(@plus, Xp, Xo./2).';
    Yp = bsxfun(@plus, Yp, Yo./2).';
    Zp = bsxfun(@plus, Zp, Zo./2).';
    Cp = index(:).';
  end
end
```

This function accepts a 3D matrix, ideally a logical mask of the volume region(s) to create a surface for, and returns 4 4-by-N matrices: `X/Y/Z` matrices for the voxel face patches and an index matrix `C` that can be used to get values from the volume data matrix for use in coloring each surface.

Here's the code to render the surfaces:

```
[X, Y, Z, C] = build_voxels(Img > 0);
rgbData = reshape([1 0 0; 1 1 0], [2 1 3]);
hSurface = patch(X, Y, Z, rgbData(Img(C), :, :), ...
                 'AmbientStrength', 0.5, ...
                 'BackFaceLighting', 'unlit', ...
                 'EdgeColor', 'none', ...
                 'FaceLighting', 'flat');
axis equal;
axis tight;
view(45, 45);
grid on;
xlabel('x-axis (voxels)');
ylabel('y-axis (voxels)');
zlabel('z-axis (voxels)');
light('Position', get(gca, 'CameraPosition'), 'Style', 'local');
```

And here's the plot:

[image]

Note that the sphere and bar surfaces are colored differently since they are labeled with values 1 and 2, respectively, in the volume data `Img`. These values are extracted from `Img` using `C` and then used as an index into `rgbData`, which contains red (first row) and yellow (second row) RGB triplets. This will create an N-by-1-by-3 matrix of [polygon face colors](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html#inputarg_C).

Comment: Wow! this is exactly what i need. Thank you so much @gnovice! Meanwhile, i don;t understand how to change the parula color map (please pardon my ignorance). I wouldn't have minded having the sphere to be red instead. Thanks once again!

Comment: @User1333: I edited my answer to show how you can control the color map.

Comment: I am sorry for bothering you, but perhaps if I could just ask you for more last thing, is it possible you could help me plot this image such that the z-axis points into the page (i.e. the image coordinate system)?

Comment: @User1333: That is controlled by the [`view`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/view.html) function. The first argument is the azimuth (rotation in the XY plane) and the second argument is the elevation. An elevation of 90 degrees will look down from above (positive z axis pointing out of the screen).

Comment: i know it's been a while i posted this, but please i need a some help still. I tried to make the image transparent and this works... only that  the red and yellow voxels both become a single color. Please, how do i make the have their separate colors in addition to being transparent? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @User1333: If you want to make the surfaces transparent, you can add `'FaceAlpha', 0.5` to the call to `patch`, adjusting the value between 0 (invisible) and 1 (opaque).

Comment: Yeah! i did this: `hSurface.FaceAlpha = 0.2;` and it works, but then when i plot another image on the original one then both the yellow and red become a single color.

Comment: @User1333: The problem is with adding to the plot, because whatever you're adding is probably modifying the [color axis](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/caxis.html) settings. The colormap I used in the example only has 2 values, and when you adjust the color axis limits the colors for each surface get mapped to just one of them. You'll need to modify your colormap, or adjust either the above surfaces or your added elements to use RGB colors instead of colormap-interpolated colors.

Comment: Thanks @gnovice: i'm finding it a bit sketchy to get this through. Could you please show me a little example or better still point me to one i could look up?

Comment: @User1333: I updated my answer to avoid the use of a colormap by specifying the surface colors directly with RGB triples. Now you can use the colormap for other images added to the plot.

Comment: @gnovie: Thank you very much for your precious time. When i run the code, it throws up an error "index exceeds matrix dimension". I realize this is coming from the line `rgbData = reshape([1 0 0; 1 1 0], [2 1 3]);`

Comment: @User1333: I'm guessing the error is actually coming from `rgbData(Img(C), :, :)`, which would indicate `Img` contains values other than 0, 1, and 2. In my example data, those are the only values `Img` could contain. If you have data with values greater than 2, you will have to create an `rgbData` variable with `N` color triplets, where `N` is the highest value in `Img`.

Comment: Oh I see! I have now changed my labeling to match yours now and it works fine. Many thanks for that. Permit me to trouble you one last time though... please how can i set the transparency of each individual phases separately?